# how to disable xPage panel with CSJS

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I'm trying to disable a panel on my xPage with CSJS.. but neither method works:

```
dojo.byId("#{id:panel1}").readonly=true;
dojo.attr("#{id:panel1}", "readonly", "true");
document.getElementById("#{id:panel1}").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` for all input elements within your panel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel
        id="panel1">
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputText1"
            value="#{sessionScope.Test}"></xp:inputText>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button
        value="Disable Input Field On Client Side"
        id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var panel1 = document.getElementById("#{id:panel1}");
            dojo.query('input', panel1).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

`dojo.query('input', panel1)` returns a collection of all input elements within panel1.

`.attr(...)` sets the attribute to every collection's element.

If you want to disable other elements within the panel too just add the element's type to the query, for example `dojo.query('input, button', panel1)` for buttons.

Comment: I'm getting this error TypeError: dojo.byId(...).attr is not a function.... or...
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).attr is not a function

Comment: I added an example XPage to show how to set `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')`

Comment: is there a way to set really read-only property instead of disabled? I need to read input components value after that

Comment: Yes, you can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` the same way: `.attr('readonly', 'readonly')` or `.attr('readonly', true)`.

Comment: could you please update your example. I have few checkboxes in the panel. and 'readonly' doesn't work. I still can click checkboxes one I click the button. But 'disabled" does work right - it disables the checkboxes

Comment: Yes, that's how readonly works: checkboxes stay selectable and buttons clickable only input fields are locked -  http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html

Comment: that explains. Thank you very much Mr. Knut